# "Благодаря" и "благосклонность", стоящие близко, смотрятся тавтологично?

Tags: тавтология

> Это не книга в строгом смысле слова — записи из личного дневника.
>   Точнее, только те, у которых стоит пометка «Рим». То есть все они
>   написаны в Риме и чаще всего именно о Риме. На протяжении лет эти
>   замечания о погоде, заметки о нравах, зарисовки бытовых сценок, цитаты
>   из мудрых трудов, с которыми я провожу время, были доступны только
>   моим друзьям — онлайн. Но **благодаря их вниманию и благосклонным
>   откликам** увидела свет книга «Моя Италия». Так я решила издать и эти
>   тексты: быть может, кому-то покажется занятным побывать «за кулисами»
>   бестселлера.

Надо ли заменять одно из слов? Чем?

---

---

P. S. Представляете, друзья, аннотация не должна превышать пятисот знаков! Я вся извелась, сокращая, но всё сохранив, - вышло?

> Это не книга в строгом смысле слова — записи из личного дневника.
>   Точнее, только те, у которых стоит пометка «Рим»: они написаны в Риме
>   и чаще всего именно о Риме. В течение лет эти замечания о погоде,
>   заметки о нравах, зарисовки бытовых сценок, цитаты из мудрых трудов,
>   с которыми провожу время, были доступны только моим LJ-друзьям.
>   Но благодаря их вниманию и тёплым откликам увидела свет книга «Моя
>   Италия». Так я решила: быть может, кому-то покажется занятным побывать
>   «за кулисами» бестселлера?

499, вот так.

УВИДИТЕ ОШИБКИ - КРИЧИТЕ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне это соседство   не показалось  криминальным, может, потому что предлог благодаря уже несколько отдалился по смыслу от глагола благодарить.  Заменить его будет трудно, синонимы изменят смысл. "Благосклонные отклики" можно заменить на "тёплые", "доброжелательные", "добрые", но как на это посмотрит автор? Попробуйте предложить, однако можно и не менять.

Answer (score 1):

*Но благодаря их вниманию и благосклонным откликам появилась и увидела свет книга «Моя Италия».*

Благодарственность и благосклонность — понятия в определённой степени противоположные по смыслу. Первое сродни жертвенности и любви, второе — выраженной симпатии.